# SQLyog Function: Syntax error when returning values from INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I am writing an SQLyog function to find the status of a client depending on the amount they have spent. The amount they have spent resides in the payment table and all the clients details reside in the clients table.

Edit: Note the function works when the output is just `CustStatus`, seems like the issue is to do with the inclusion of the other return values.

This is the error I am receiving:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ' VARCHAR(50), VARCHAR(50), VARCHAR(10)
>   DETERMINISTIC
>
> BEGIN  DECLARE k1 INT(11' at line 2

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DTC_VIP_members $$
CREATE FUNCTION DTC_VIP_members (v1 INT(11))
RETURNS INT(11), VARCHAR(50), VARCHAR(50), VARCHAR(10) DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN 
DECLARE k1 INT(11);
DECLARE CustStatus VARCHAR(10);
SELECT SUM(payment.SaleAmt) INTO k1
FROM payment
INNER JOIN clients
ON payment.client_id = clients.client_id
WHERE payment.client_id = v1;
IF k1 >= 300 THEN
    UPDATE clients  
    SET clients.CustStatus = 'VIP';
ELSE
    UPDATE clients  
    SET clients.CustStatus = 'Non-VIP';
END IF;
RETURN clients.client_id, clients.first_name, clients.last_name, clients.CustStatus;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!
Thank you for taking the time to look and reply Slava!
Yes, your approach is a much better design and would probably all my silly SQL syntax errors.
I learnt that with the SQLyog server version I am working on that Functions can only RETURN one value. So my design was flawed from the beginning.

Since the SQLyog function can only return single value “vip” or “non-vip”.
I tried using a select such as to achieve the desired results. 
Select firstName, lastName, ….  DTC_VIP_members(….);

Hopefully, this answer helps any other beginners trying to learn SQL from the free version of SQLyog. 
Updoots to the left

```
   DELIMITER $$

    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `DTC_VIP_members`$$ 

    CREATE DEFINER=`yadda`@`%` FUNCTION `DTC_VIP_members`(v1 INT(11)) RETURNS VARCHAR(10) CHARSET latin1 
        DETERMINISTIC 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE k1 INT(11); 
        DECLARE CustStatus VARCHAR(10); 
        SELECT SUM(SaleAmt) INTO k1 
        FROM payment 
        WHERE client_id = v1; 
        IF k1 >= 300 THEN
            SET CustStatus = 'VIP'; 
        ELSE
            SET CustStatus = 'Non-VIP'; 
        END IF;
        RETURN CustStatus; 
        END$$

    DELIMITER ;

    --------------------------------------

    SELECT  first_name, last_name, email, mobile_number, `DTC_VIP_members`(client_id) 
    FROM clients;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but your approach looks wrong.

First: I advice to use STORED PROCEDURE instead FUNCTION

Second: using `UPDATE` statement without `WHERE` condition cause to update all rows in table that also seems wrong.

So we stored procedure can looks as:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DTC_VIP_members $$
CREATE PROCEDURE DTC_VIP_members (v1 INT(11))
BEGIN 
    DECLARE k1 INT(11);
    DECLARE CustStatus VARCHAR(10);

    SELECT SUM(payment.SaleAmt) INTO k1
    FROM payment
    INNER JOIN clients
    ON payment.client_id = clients.client_id
    WHERE payment.client_id = v1;

    IF k1 >= 300 THEN
        UPDATE clients  
        SET clients.CustStatus = 'VIP'
        WHERE clients.client_id = v1; -- update only one record
    ELSE
        UPDATE clients  
        SET clients.CustStatus = 'Non-VIP'
        WHERE clients.client_id = v1; -- update only one record
    END IF;

    -- select relevant data
    SELECT 
        clients.client_id, clients.first_name, clients.last_name, clients.CustStatus 
    FROM clients
    WHERE clients.client_id = v1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```